# php&MySQL display table with loop

Tags: php, mysql

I need to display results from a table, however my loop doesn't produce the table accordingly, the TH are looped for each result, please assist

```
<?php foreach ($results as $results) :  ?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>GBR</th>
        <th>EUR</th>
        <th>USD</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $results['date'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $results['gbr']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $results['eur']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $results['usd']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to include table and th tag in for each loop you just need to put tr in loop.

```
 <table border="1">
     <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>GBR</th>
      <th>EUR</th>
     <th>USD</th>
   </tr>
    <?php foreach ($results as $result) :  ?>
     <tr>
        <td><?=  $result['date'];?></td>
        <td><?=  $result['gbr']; ?></td>
        <td><?=  $result['eur']; ?></td>
        <td><?=  $result['usd']; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </table>
```

Try this code hope is helps

Comment: Thank you it works now, i typed exactly as instructed above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your tr within the loop.

try this:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>GBR</th>
    <th>EUR</th>
    <th>USD</th>
  </tr>

  <?php foreach ($results as $results) :  ?>

  <tr>
        <td><?php echo $results['date'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $results['gbr']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $results['eur']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $results['usd']; ?></td>
  </tr>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `foreach` loop where you need dynamically show the data.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>GBR</th>
        <th>EUR</th>
        <th>USD</th>
    </tr>
<?php foreach ($results as $results) :  ?>  
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $results['date'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $results['gbr']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $results['eur']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $results['usd']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop table every time.Just start loop to `<tr>`

```
<?php foreach ($results as $results) : ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $results['date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $results['gbr']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $results['eur']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $results['usd']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```